# How do I get the @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation

Tags: spring, oauth, upgrade

Upgraded to Spring Boot 2, now the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation is missing because the import is now incorrect.

I found some docs on this issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11032#issuecomment-372100443

but it doesn't say what to replace the import with. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you include the gradle dependency?

Comment: I'm not using gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue and found you have to add the [Spring Security OAuth2 AutoConfigure dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure/2.0.1.RELEASE).